# what does reserved unresolvable URI mean?

Tags: html, http, camera, uri, opera

I found a paragraph about [camera usage on Opera web browser](http://my.opera.com/core/blog/2011/03/23/webcam-orientation-preview):

> We have simplified the proposed GeneratedStream interface by not
>   implementing its proposed methods and attributes. The Stream object
>   returned in the success callback should be assigned directly to a
>   video element's src attribute. When a video element's src parameter
>   has been assigned a Stream object and that attribute is subsequently
>   queried the attribute returns the **reserved**, though **unresolvable**, URI
>   of about:streamurl.

However, I dont know what reserved unresolvable URI is. Can anyone help me? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it says that `about:streamurl` is a magic keyword url, which can't be used for anything else than what it is. But as any URI if you enter it in the addressbar it doesn't resolve to anything in particular.

There are others URI which are not resolvable but meaningful. I encourage you to look at `urn:`. For example ISBN organizations has released an RFC on how to create [URN for ISBN](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3187). That helps define URI (keys) which identifies a precise book, but which are not resolvable. You could use it for example in a quote. A quote from a book by Kamo no Chomei

```
<blockquote cite="urn:isbn:978-2-35873-023-5">
    <p>Si le nid se déplaçait au gré des vagues, 
    il dériverait je ne sais où au moindre souffle 
    de vent, serait brisé par les flots, ou bien 
    tomberait aux mains des gens.</p>
</blockquote>
```

Then a search engine indexing Web pages could collect these URN:ISBN and create a quote db with references to the book it is coming from with authors and titles.

Comment: @lovesunset could you mark the answer? So it is going out of our radar. Thanks ! :)